# Execute builds only for some gradle modules in project

Tags: gradle, gradle-task

I have a project utilities with a build.gradle. utilities has some modules named util, util2, util3, ...
In a task I want to execute first :util2:build and :util5:build. But I do not know how to write such a task. This fails:

```
task executePreBuild() {
:util2:build
:util5:build
}
```

In commandline

gradlew clean :util2:build :util5:build

can be executed. But this is not my purporse.
I want to execute

gradlew clean executePreBuild someOtherTask build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using `dependsOn`:

```
task executePreBuild {
    dependsOn ":util2:build"
    dependsOn ":util5:build"
}
```